# Varargs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variadic-functions

I want to write a constructor which apllies variable number of arguments. E.g.

```
var Const= function(<formalParameters>){
    this.obj={val:formalParameter1, {val:formalParameter2, {....}}}
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: With [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Comment: You could pass the arguments in a hash object `(a {} thing).`